# svn up --accept theirs-full --force and local file with same name

Tags: svn

Sometimes, but not every time, when i do svn up and already have local file with same name error occurs

```
$ svn update --accept theirs-full --force
Fetching external item into 'dir'
svn: warning: Failed to add file 'dir/subdir/file.txt': an unversioned file of the same name already exists

At revision 19818.

$ svn st
Performing status on external item at 'dir'
!       dir
?       dir/subdir/file.txt
```

But if try like this

```
$ svn up dir/subdir/file.txt
svn: Failed to add file 'dir/subdir/file.txt': an unversioned file of the same name already exists

$ svn up --force dir/subdir/file.txt
E    dir/subdir/file.txt
Updated to revision 19818.

$ svn st dir/subdir/file.txt
$
```

all works.

I understand something wrong? 
Is this somehow related to external repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `--force` option is not applied when updating the external repo. The [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) and `svn up -h` doesn't explain this behavior. But since this seems a safe thing to do, it's not really surprising.

In general, you can see in the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) that the behavior of `svn update` is not the same when invoked on the main checkout and when invoked directly on the checkout of externals. That is, when invoked in the main checkout, the command is kind of *softer*, does not do all the changes it normally would on a normal checkout. When invoked on the externals directly, it behaves as normal.